# Unsatisfied dependencies for class at injection point. Reference not found com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster

Tags: java, maven, cassandra, wildfly, datastax-java-driver

I am working JavaEE and Cassandra DB with wildfly server.
wildfly server is unable to deploy .war with the following error log:

```
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type CassandraConnector with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject com.MyMainClass.CC
  at com.MyMainClass.CC(MyMainClass.java:0)
WELD-001474: Class com.cassandra.CassandraConnector is on the classpath, but was ignored because a class it references was not found: com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster from [Module "deployment.Services-0.0.1.war:main" from Service Module Loader].

    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:359)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:281)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:134)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:155)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:518)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:68)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:66)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:60)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:53)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    ... 3 more
```

Basically I am unable to identify the problematic point let alone the solution. Is this because the wildfly server is unable to connect with Cassandra DB running on the System? Or the problem lies somewhere else?
If the server configuration is the issue, what is the correct solution for that? I have tried many except Cassandra JDBC (not even sure if that works).
Just to clarify, all dependencies are added into the project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the dependency that provides `com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster` - it's in the [driver-core package](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.cassandra/cassandra-driver-core) that you can include via Maven, or other build system.

P.S. Don't forget to include its dependencies as well...

Comment: The dependencies were added already as I mentioned in my question.
But I don't know how it started working afterwards. Somehow the dependencies were either not installed or not picked up by the system. I don't know.
But it worked. On one build, it showed the dependencies are installing and afterwards the problem was resolved. 
Anyways, you have pointed out in the right direction